# Debian Wheezy 7.1 - can't launch Skype or Firefox

Tags: bash, path, debian

I've installed Skype by using `dkpg` and when I try to run it, this is what I get `-bash: /usr/bin/skype: No such file or directory`. Which is very strange since `ls -l | grep skype` shows this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    30717480 May  7 01:43 skype
```

I had similiar problems when I installed FireFox, but since I didn't need it all that much, didn't care. However, I do need Skype on Linux.

Output of my `$PATH` variable:

```
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/max/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Anyone care to explain?... Because I'm stunned.

Comment: have you tried to run using absolute path ? like `/usr/bin/skype`

Comment: I've tried it now... and still the same result.

Comment: `ldd /usr/bin/skype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is the perennial 32-bit application on a 64-bit system issue.

Does the following help?

```
[root@host]# dpkg --add-architecture i386
[root@host]# apt-get update #Will take a while
[root@host]# apt-get install ia32-libs #Will download and install ~100-200 MB of data
[user@host]$ skype&
```

Comment: Yup! This was it. I did the first step, didn't follow up. With minor detail, he made me run `apt-get -f install` to resolve some issues, but couldn't have gone there by myself. Thanks.